# integrate Google Places Autocomplete in my search bar

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, google-maps

i want to integrate Google Places Autocomplete in my search bar. google provides an API for this
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html

i want to integrate the same in my ipad application. reverse geocoding has already been done.

i hv been scratching my head for the same, it seems no one has ever integrated this. plz help me in the same.

thnx in advance.

Comment: You need to provide some more context?  Why are you not able to integrate it?  It's a web service, and you should be able to submit RESTful requests to it (or a proxy) via the app you're building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html) provided for guidance.